# Awkward session error with magento cookie parsing in Android App

Tags: android, magento, cookies, android-volley

I am working on an Android app which uses sessions by managing cookies from an API based on magento backend.
On the app side, I am using Volley Library for network request. I have successfully got the network response and from that I have fetched the "Set-Cookie" value. Now when I am attaching this cookie to the header but the server doesn't validate my session.

The strange thing is I tried to request the same JSON request from a rest client and then used the cookie from that and added to the header as a static value and then I was provided session access. I completely have no idea regarding what is going on. Why the cookies from rest client is working while the cookie value from my network response doesn't.

Here is my SignIn Activity code where I am doing a login json request and storing the cookie value.

```
package com.paaltao.activity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.NetworkError;
import com.android.volley.NetworkResponse;
import com.android.volley.NoConnectionError;
import com.android.volley.ParseError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.ServerError;
import com.android.volley.TimeoutError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.github.mrengineer13.snackbar.SnackBar;
import com.paaltao.R;
import com.paaltao.classes.MyApp;
import com.paaltao.classes.PersistentCookieStore;
import com.paaltao.classes.ProgressWheel;
import com.paaltao.classes.SharedPreferenceClass;
import com.paaltao.logging.L;
import com.paaltao.network.VolleySingleton;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.net.CookieHandler;
import java.net.CookieManager;
import java.net.CookiePolicy;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;

import static com.paaltao.extras.Keys.UserCredentials.*;
import static com.paaltao.extras.urlEndPoints.BASE_URL;
import static com.paaltao.extras.urlEndPoints.LOGIN;
import static com.paaltao.extras.urlEndPoints.UAT_BASE_URL;

public class SignInActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String SET_COOKIE_KEY = "Set-Cookie";
    private static final String COOKIE_KEY = "Cookie";
    private static final String SESSION_COOKIE = "sessionid";
    Button SignUpBtn;
    Button SignInBtn;
    ProgressWheel progressBar;
    EditText email, password;
    TextView forgotPassword;
    String emailId,accessToken,api_ver,token,firstName,lastName,cookie,newCookie;
    Boolean login_success;
    SharedPreferenceClass preferenceClass;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) this.findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        toolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent));
        this.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        this.setTitle("Sign in");
        initiate();
        onItemClick();



    }

    public void initiate() {
        SignUpBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signUpBtn);
        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email_field);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password_field);
        SignInBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signInBtn);
        forgotPassword = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.forgot_password);
        progressBar = (ProgressWheel)findViewById(R.id.action_progress);
        preferenceClass = new SharedPreferenceClass(getApplicationContext());

    }

    public boolean validationCheck() {
        if (email.getText().toString().length() == 0)
            email.setError("Please provide your email. Your email must be in the format abc@xyz.com");
        else if (password.getText().toString().length() == 0)
            password.setError("Please provide a password");
        else return true;
        return false;
    }

    public void onItemClick() {
        SignInBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (validationCheck()) {
                    sendJsonRequest();
                }

            }
        });

        SignUpBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SignInActivity.this, SignUpActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        forgotPassword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SignInActivity.this, ForgotPasswordActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    public static String getRequestUrl() {

        return UAT_BASE_URL
                + LOGIN;

    }



    public void sendJsonRequest() {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        final JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        final JSONObject signIn = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonObject.put("email", email.getText().toString());
            jsonObject.put("password", password.getText().toString());
            signIn.put("emailSignIn", jsonObject);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        RequestQueue requestQueue = VolleySingleton.getsInstance().getRequestQueue();
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, getRequestUrl(), signIn, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {

                if (progressBar.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                parseJSONResponse(jsonObject);
                //Calling the Snackbar
                Log.e("response", jsonObject.toString());

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                if (progressBar.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                if (volleyError instanceof TimeoutError || volleyError instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                    new SnackBar.Builder(SignInActivity.this)
                            .withMessage("No Internet Connection!")
                            .withTextColorId(R.color.white)
                            .withDuration((short) 6000)
                            .show();

                } else if (volleyError instanceof AuthFailureError) {

                    //TODO
                } else if (volleyError instanceof ServerError) {

                    //TODO
                } else if (volleyError instanceof NetworkError) {

                    //TODO
                } else if (volleyError instanceof ParseError) {

                    //TODO
                }

            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                // since we don't know which of the two underlying network vehicles
                // will Volley use, we have to handle and store session cookies manually
                // MyApp.get().checkSessionCookie(response.headers);
                L.m(response.headers.toString());
                L.m(Arrays.toString(response.data));

                L.m(response.headers.get("Set-Cookie"));
                preferenceClass.saveCookiee(response.headers.get("Set-Cookie"));
                cookie = response.headers.get("Set-Cookie");
                String[] splitCookie = cookie.split(";");
                String[] splitSessionId = splitCookie[0].split("=");
                newCookie = splitSessionId[1];
                //cookie = response.headers.values().toString();
                Log.e("split",newCookie);
                preferenceClass.saveCookie(newCookie);
                return super.parseNetworkResponse(response);
                }
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders ()throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> headers = super.getHeaders();

                    if (headers == null
                            || headers.equals(Collections.emptyMap())) {
                        headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    }

//                MyApp.get().addSessionCookie(headers);

                    return headers;
                }
            }

            ;
            requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
        }

    public void parseJSONResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
        if (jsonObject == null || jsonObject.length() == 0) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            JSONObject dataObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject(KEY_DATA);
            JSONObject signInObject = dataObject.getJSONObject(KEY_SIGN_IN);
            JSONObject accessTokenObject = signInObject.getJSONObject(KEY_ACCESS_TOKEN);
            JSONObject errorNodeObject = dataObject.getJSONObject(KEY_ERROR_NODE);
            if(dataObject.has(KEY_VENDOR)){
                if (dataObject.isNull(KEY_VENDOR)){
                    return;
                }
            else {JSONObject vendorObject = dataObject.getJSONObject(KEY_VENDOR);
                if(vendorObject != null){
                String vendor_login = vendorObject.getString(KEY_HAS_SHOP);
                if(vendor_login != null && vendor_login.contains("true")){
                    preferenceClass.saveVendorLoginSuccess(vendor_login);
                }}}
            }

            emailId = signInObject.getString(KEY_EMAIL);
            firstName = signInObject.getString(KEY_FIRST_NAME);
            lastName = signInObject.getString(KEY_LAST_NAME);
            login_success = signInObject.getBoolean(KEY_USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS);

            preferenceClass.saveFirstName(firstName);
            preferenceClass.saveLastName(lastName);
            preferenceClass.saveUserEmail(emailId);

            if(accessTokenObject.has(KEY_TOKEN)){
            token = accessTokenObject.getString(KEY_TOKEN);}



            String errorCode = errorNodeObject.getString(KEY_ERROR_CODE);
            String message = errorNodeObject.getString(KEY_MESSAGE);
            if (login_success){
                Log.e("TAG",login_success.toString());
                if (token!= null && token.length()!=0){
                    preferenceClass.saveAccessToken(token);
                    preferenceClass.saveUserEmail(emailId);

                    Intent intent = new Intent(SignInActivity.this,HomeActivity.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            }
            else{
                Log.e("TAG",login_success.toString());
                new SnackBar.Builder(SignInActivity.this)
                        .withMessage("Username or Password is Incorrect!")
                        .withTextColorId(R.color.white)
                        .withDuration((short) 6000)
                        .show();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

and this is the code for the fragment where I am doing a check session test with the stored cookie received from network response (Note: I replaced the cookie with the one I got from rest client and it worked!!)

```
package com.paaltao.fragment;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.NetworkError;
import com.android.volley.NetworkResponse;
import com.android.volley.NoConnectionError;
import com.android.volley.ParseError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.ServerError;
import com.android.volley.TimeoutError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpClientStack;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpHeaderParser;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpStack;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.github.mrengineer13.snackbar.SnackBar;
import com.paaltao.R;
import com.paaltao.activity.AddressActivity;
import com.paaltao.activity.IntroPageActivity;
import com.paaltao.activity.PaaltaoInfo;
import com.paaltao.activity.EditProfileActivity;
import com.paaltao.classes.MyApp;
import com.paaltao.classes.PersistentCookieStore;
import com.paaltao.classes.SharedPreferenceClass;
import com.paaltao.logging.L;
import com.paaltao.network.VolleySingleton;

import org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCookieStore;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.net.CookieHandler;
import java.net.CookieManager;
import java.net.CookiePolicy;
import java.net.CookieStore;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import cn.pedant.SweetAlert.SweetAlertDialog;

import static com.paaltao.extras.Keys.UserCredentials.KEY_ACCESS_TOKEN;
import static com.paaltao.extras.Keys.UserCredentials.KEY_DATA;
import static com.paaltao.extras.Keys.UserCredentials.KEY_ERROR_CODE;
import static com.paaltao.extras.Keys.UserCredentials.KEY_ERROR_NODE;
import static com.paaltao.extras.Keys.UserCredentials.KEY_MESSAGE;
import static com.paaltao.extras.Keys.UserCredentials.KEY_SIGN_OUT;
import static com.paaltao.extras.urlEndPoints.BASE_URL;
import static com.paaltao.extras.urlEndPoints.SIGN_OUT;
import static com.paaltao.extras.urlEndPoints.UAT_BASE_URL;

//This is a user account fragment.
public class AccountFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String SET_COOKIE_KEY = "Set-Cookie";
    private static final String COOKIE_KEY = "Cookie";
    private static final String SESSION_COOKIE = "sessionid";
    RelativeLayout accountLink,my_address,signOut;
    View view;
    String accessToken;
    TextView firstName,lastName,about,terms,privacy,notificationSettings;
    SharedPreferenceClass preferenceClass;
    SweetAlertDialog dialog;
    Context context;



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_account, container, false);
        initialize();
        onItemClick();

        return view;
    }

    public static String getRequestUrl() {

        return UAT_BASE_URL
                + SIGN_OUT;

    }

    public void sendJsonRequest(){
        final JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        final JSONObject signOut = new JSONObject();
        try{
            jsonObject.put("accessToken","67drd56g");
            signOut.put("signOut", jsonObject);



        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        RequestQueue requestQueue = VolleySingleton.getsInstance().getRequestQueue();
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,getRequestUrl(),signOut,new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {

                Log.e("error", jsonObject.toString());
                Log.e("json", signOut.toString());


                parseJSONResponse(jsonObject);

            }
        },new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                if (volleyError instanceof TimeoutError || volleyError instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                    new SnackBar.Builder(getActivity())
                            .withMessage("No Internet Connection!")
                            .withTextColorId(R.color.white)
                            .withDuration((short) 6000)
                            .show();

                } else if (volleyError instanceof AuthFailureError) {

                    //TODO
                } else if (volleyError instanceof ServerError) {

                    //TODO
                } else if (volleyError instanceof NetworkError) {

                    //TODO
                } else if (volleyError instanceof ParseError) {

                    //TODO
                }

            }

        });
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }


    public void parseJSONResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
        if (jsonObject == null || jsonObject.length() == 0) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            JSONObject dataObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject(KEY_DATA);
            JSONObject signOutObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject(KEY_SIGN_OUT);
            JSONObject errorNodeObject = dataObject.getJSONObject(KEY_ERROR_NODE);


            accessToken = signOutObject.getString(KEY_ACCESS_TOKEN);



            String errorCode = errorNodeObject.getString(KEY_ERROR_CODE);
            String message = errorNodeObject.getString(KEY_MESSAGE);

            if (errorCode.equals("200")){
                preferenceClass.clearAccessToken();
                preferenceClass.clearFirstName();
                preferenceClass.clearLastName();
                preferenceClass.clearUserEmail();
                Log.e("accessToken",accessToken);
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),IntroPageActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
                getActivity().finish();

            }
            else{
                new SnackBar.Builder(getActivity())
                        .withMessage("Error in signing out")
                        .withTextColorId(R.color.white)
                        .withDuration((short) 6000)
                        .show();

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    public void sendJsonRequest1(){
        final JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        final JSONObject sessionCheck = new JSONObject();
        try{
            jsonObject.put("accessToken","67drd56g");
            sessionCheck.put("checkSession", jsonObject);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        RequestQueue requestQueue = VolleySingleton.getsInstance().getRequestQueue();
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,getRequestUrl1(),sessionCheck,new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {

                Log.e("error", jsonObject.toString());
                Log.e("json", sessionCheck.toString());
                Log.e("url",getRequestUrl());
                L.m(jsonObject.toString());

                            }
        },new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                if (volleyError instanceof TimeoutError || volleyError instanceof NoConnectionError) {

                } else if (volleyError instanceof AuthFailureError) {

                    //TODO
                } else if (volleyError instanceof ServerError) {

                    //TODO
                } else if (volleyError instanceof NetworkError) {

                    //TODO
                } else if (volleyError instanceof ParseError) {

                    //TODO
                }

            }

        })
        {
            @Override
            protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                // since we don't know which of the two underlying network vehicles
                // will Volley use, we have to handle and store session cookies manually
                //   MyApp.get().checkSessionCookie(response.headers);
                //L.m(response.headers.toString());


                return super.parseNetworkResponse(response);
            }
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> headers = super.getHeaders();

                if (headers == null
                        || headers.equals(Collections.emptyMap())) {
                    headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                }

                String sessionId = preferenceClass.getCookie();
                Log.e("cOOOKIE","frontend="+sessionId);
                Log.e("sessionid","frontend=7fgenogpffjvvmdg1gf439hta7");

                   // headers.put(COOKIE_KEY,"frontend="+sessionId);
                    headers.put(COOKIE_KEY,"frontend=e7qfldgsnf7aop381a8vk3b866");
                return headers;
            }};
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);

    }


    private String getRequestUrl1() {
        return UAT_BASE_URL+"checkSession";
    }


    public void initialize(){
        accountLink = (RelativeLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.account_link);
        my_address = (RelativeLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.my_address);
        signOut = (RelativeLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.signOut);
        preferenceClass = new SharedPreferenceClass(getActivity());
        firstName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.firstName);
        lastName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.lastName);
        about = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.about);
        terms = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.terms);
        privacy = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.privacy);
        if(preferenceClass.getFirstName() != null)
        firstName.setText(preferenceClass.getFirstName());
        if(preferenceClass.getLastName() != null)
        lastName.setText(preferenceClass.getLastName());
        notificationSettings = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.notification_settings);
    }

    public void onItemClick(){

        notificationSettings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sendJsonRequest1();
            }
        });

        accountLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), EditProfileActivity.class));
            }
        });
        my_address.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), AddressActivity.class));
            }
        });

        signOut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                confirmSignOut();
            }
        });

        about.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), PaaltaoInfo.class);
                intent.putExtra("page","about_paaltao");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        terms.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), PaaltaoInfo.class);
                intent.putExtra("page","terms");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        privacy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), PaaltaoInfo.class);
                intent.putExtra("page","privacy_policy");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    public void confirmSignOut(){
        dialog = new SweetAlertDialog(getActivity(), SweetAlertDialog.NORMAL_TYPE);
        dialog.setTitleText("Signout")
                .setContentText("Are you sure you want to sign out?")
                .setConfirmText("Yes")
                .setCancelText("No")
                .setConfirmClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sDialog) {
                        sendJsonRequest();
                    }
                })
                .setCancelClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sDialog) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                })
                .show();
    }



    }
```

There is no structural difference between the rest client cookie and the one recieved in app:

rest client cookie : frontend=48b1i38fgls4d0241mp6d6rrr0
app side cookie : frontend=86n349m3patu37eud00ntobd90

Thanks in advance. It will be a life saver if some one can help.

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: Yes! It was about handling the cookies in the header.